# Getting gradle error while turn on [Enabled advanced profiling] in configurations

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 3.0
gradle 4.1

the message is:

23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForOsGldDebug'.
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > 4
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:12:04.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForOsGldDebug'.
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
23:12:04.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.ProfilerTransform.accept(ProfilerTransform.java:61)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.profiler.ProfilerTransform.accept(ProfilerTransform.java:38)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.CustomClassTransform.apply(CustomClassTransform.java:301)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.CustomClassTransform.transformJar(CustomClassTransform.java:273)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.CustomClassTransform.transform(CustomClassTransform.java:186)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
23:12:04.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
23:12:04.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
23:12:04.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
23:12:04.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 27 more
23:12:04.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:12:04.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:12:04.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org